# Google EventReservation markup whitelisting

Tags: google-schemas

We would like to send Event Reservation markup along with our order confirmation email. The schema was implemented using JSON+LD and following the requirements set by [google's reference document for event reservation](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/event-reservation).

We filled the form required by Google and sent one of our confirmation emails to the specified email address with the markup data. As a reply we were informed that "the schema was **empty**". When trying to request more information we received a no-reply message from the address that contacted us.

I'm adding a link to the html of the email sent along with the form confirmation emails with the markup data [here](https://gist.github.com/ribeirojr/75224ecad591ab8fada08528b9953c09). Our sent email contents are base64 encoded, could that be the cause of the email being rejected? If not, what other actions can we take to get the event reservation markup displayed in our emails?

Comment: I'll help you out. Could you please shoot over an email to ftmedallada@gmail.com from your production environment w/ the markup for event reservation included? I'll check out the raw source that is received in my inbox.

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?